# Unable to see inference result in MMsegmentation 1.x

Tags: semantic-segmentation

After the model is well trained using MMsegmentation 1.x, I tried to perform inferences. I only see the background image without segmentation results.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mmseg.apis import init_model, inference_model, show_result_pyplot
from mmengine import Config

config_file = 'mask2former_swin-s_8xb2-160k_ade20k-512x512.py'
checkpoint_path= "iter_25000.pth"
img_path =" imge_1.jpg"

cfg = Config.fromfile(config_file)
model = init_model(cfg, checkpoint_path, 'cuda:0')
img = mmcv.imread(img_path)

result = inference_model(model, img)

vis_result =show_result_pyplot(model, img, result)
plt.imshow(mmcv.bgr2rgb(vis_result))
```